# Is it ok to return a variable or object by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, scope, reference, return, storage-duration

So i'm curious whether or not its ok to pass a variable or an object by reference from one file to another in C++ like in the examples below.

String example:

```cpp
int main() {
  //
  std::cout << GetName() << std::endl;
}

std::string name = "Paul";

std::string& GetName() {
  return name;
}
```

Object example:

```cpp
int main() {
  //
  std::cout << GetEmployee().GetAge() << std::endl;
}

Employee employee;

Employee& GetEmployee() {
  return employee;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is safe. But you might as well declare the variable as `extern` in the header, then you don't need the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the above works, but is not commonly used. It works only because in your case the objects whose address you return are static. The following will not work:

```cpp
std::string& GetName() {
  std::string name = "Paul";
  return name;
}
```

Note that the compiler might let you do this, however since the variable `name` is allocated on the stack, its address points to unallocated stack space after the method has ended, and accessing it will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in these code examples is not that variables with static storage duration are returned by reference. You may return such variables by reference because they will be alive after exiting functions.

The problem is that you should avoid to declare variables in file scopes.

Pay attention to that you may not return from functions references to objects with automatic storage duration because they will not be alive after exiting functions.